# How to SET postgres application_name in a basic PHP script

Tags: php, postgresql, application-name

I'm trying to develop a script to SET application_name log feature in PHP application.

```
pg_query("SET application_name = 'Test log line'");
```

What I tried it above code. But it give following error,

> Warning: pg_query(): Query failed: ERROR:  unrecognized configuration parameter "application_name" in ...

This means I can't simply execute SET application_name query from `pg_query()` function.

Can anyone help me to find a way to set this from a PHP script.

Thank you!

Comment: Weird looks ok to me. What version of postgres are you using?

Comment: Client: postgresql-client-8.4 Server: postgresql-8.4

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're on an old PostgreSQL version.

`application_name` was [introduced in 9.0](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/runtime-config-logging.html). Compare to the 8.4 documentation with the link at the top.

You need to upgrade or skip using the feature.

In general, if you get errors that indicate that PostgreSQL has no idea what you're talking about - functions not found, views missing, syntax errors on what looks like the documented syntax, etc - then you should be thinking "am I reading the manual for my version".

Comment: Thanks! Let me check on that :)